# A dead lock in Mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, deadlock

Today, I encountered a strange dead lock problem in mysql 5.7. Here is the detail:

[image]

and the table is :

```
CREATE TABLE `xs_pv` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id',
`nh_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '小说编号',
`day` date NOT NULL COMMENT '日期',
`pv` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '页面浏览量',
`uv` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '独立访客',
`name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `nh_id` (`nh_id`),
 KEY `day` (`day`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19179 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='小说访问统计表';
```

can anybody tell me how the dead lock is formed, thanks very much !!!!!!!

Comment: A deadlock is not a problem. It's a warning.

Comment: but i just want to know how, how the deadlock is formed, can you help me ? THX